# C Simple Linked List - Wrong output

Tags: c

I'm printing out the Head and Tail of the Linked List when an element is added, Fairly simple.

```
int main(){

    struct node{
        struct node* next;
        struct node* previous;
        double value;
    };

    struct LinkedList{
        struct node* head;
        struct node* tail;
    };

    void addValue(struct LinkedList* list,double newValue){
        struct node newNode;
        newNode.next = NULL;
        newNode.value=newValue;
        if(list->head == NULL){
            newNode.previous=NULL;
            list->head= &newNode;
            list->tail=&newNode;


        }
        else
        {
            newNode.previous= list->tail;
            list->tail->next= &newNode;
            list->tail= &newNode;



        }
            printf("%f\n",list->head->value);
            printf("%f\n",list->tail->value);

    }

    struct LinkedList l1;
    l1.head=NULL;
    l1.tail=NULL;
    addValue(&l1,5);
    addValue(&l1,6);
    addValue(&l1,7);
    addValue(&l1,8);


}
```

But the output I get is

> 5.000000
>   5.000000
>   6.000000
>   6.000000
>   7.000000
>   7.000000
>   8.000000
>   8.000000

Instead what I expect

> 5.000000
>   5.000000
>   5.000000
>   6.000000
>   5.000000
>   7.000000
>   5.000000
>   8.000000

Any idea why?

Comment: you should create new nodes on the heap with the `malloc` command instead of on the stack as currently is done.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry Good catch, it looks like dangling pointers.

Comment: @remyabel you can try to write my catch in an answer if you want, I have some other stuff to do ;)

Comment: Guess I was sleepy :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should create `newNode` on the heap. When the function exits, the pointers are no longer pointing to valid memory. Luckily, the changes you need to make are minimal.

```
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->value=newValue;
    if(list->head == NULL){
        newNode->previous=NULL;
        list->head= newNode;
        list->tail=newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->previous= list->tail;
        list->tail->next= newNode;
        list->tail=newNode;
    }
```

And to avoid memory leaks you should `free` your pointers. Here's an example implementation:

```
void deleteList(struct node** head_ref)
{
   struct node* current = *head_ref;
   struct node* next;

   while (current != NULL)
   {
       next = current->next;
       free(current);
       current = next;
   }

   *head_ref = NULL;
}
deleteList(&l1.head);
```

I tested it in `valgrind` and that should eliminate your leaks.

Comment: And don't forget to implenent delete function so the memory will be released at the end

Comment: maybe you can mention that the memory should be `free`d  too, to complete the implementation

Answer (score 0):

By defining struct node newNode; in void addValue(struct LinkedList* list,double newValue), memory gets allocated on the stack. so when control from the function returns, no more access to stack. values are gone !!!!. Thats its required to allocate from heap, dynamic memory where it cna be accesses until it is freed.